# How to create a conversational chat with react native app?

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

I am creating react native app. In there I want to create something like this. There I want to create a chat when a user speaks the start and destination to the app it should speak back to the user about the road. I searched a lot on the Internet but I was unable to find any good way to create a live chat with the app in order to get the start and destination from the user. It means I want something like this.when user say hi to the app it should also say Hi. Then It should say give your starting point and after that app should ask for the destination. Can Someone help me to create this small live chat with my app in react native?. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the text to speech using save react-native-tts and convert the speech to text react-native-voice.

for the chat react-native-gifted-chat you can use this

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using npm package `react-simple-chatbot` also adding Speech-to-Text(STT) for voice input and Text-to-speech(TTS) for voice output.

Check the NPM packages :

STT - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-speech-to-text

TTS - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tts

Or Both combined here https://github.com/pwcremin/react-native-watson

Hope it helps you..!

-Praz